# What's the relationship between google's different token types? And how can I use the string token with their PHP lib?

Tags: php, google-signin

It appears that google has two types of tokens, and I'm having trouble migrating from the old Google+ Sign in to the Google Sign in, as described here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide

I am using the google php client to connect to google APIs:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($appId);
    $client->setClientSecret($secret);
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
```

Above is my code that worked on the old Google+ sign in. $token was a json encoded format of

```
[
    created: original_token.issued_at,
    access_token: original_token.access_token,
    expires_in: original_token.expires_in
]
```

The access token had a format with two segments like:

```
xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I use the new format from the migration, I am calling `googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token` which gives me a JWT token format that has 3 segments, and is MUCH longer.

I am using this method which appears to be the newer one and returns a string token:

When I put that id_token into the same json object as the access_token, i get an error that the token is in the wrong format. If I try to base64 decode the original access_token it looks like binary. So I'm not sure how to convert this new id_token into a format that I can use with this API.

How can I convert this?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is unclear what you're trying to do.

The JWT, which looks like this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI3NjEzMjY3OTgwNjktcjVtbGpsbG4xcmQ0bHJiaGc3NWVmZ2lncDM2bTc4ajVAZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvcHJlZGljdGlvbiIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9vL29hdXRoMi90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTMyODU1NDM4NSwiaWF0IjoxMzI4NTUwNzg1fQ.ixOUGehweEVX_UKXv5BbbwVEdcz6AYS-6uQV6fGorGKrHf3LIJnyREw9evE-gs2bmMaQI5_UbabvI4k-mQE4kBqtmSpTzxYBL1TCd7Kv5nTZoUC1CmwmWCFqT9RE6D7XSgPUh_jF1qskLa2w0rxMSjwruNKbysgRNctZPln7cqQ
```

Is part of an authentication *request*.

If the request is granted you'll get a response like this:

```
{
  "access_token" : "1/8xbJqaOZXSUZbHLl5EOtu1pxz3fmmetKx9W8CV4t79M",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

Which has the token you want to actually use in a request.

Comment: It looks like if I pull the `googleUser` object apart in JS, there is both an id_token (the long one which has a verifiable signature) and an access_token (the short one which requires server verification). I have figured out I can call $client->verifyIdToken($id_token) and it validates. But I don't have any way to authenticate for making API calls to google. It seems like the google docs are wrong, and I should just send the access_token to my server instead of the id_token?

Comment: or is the auto token not supposed to give me access to google APIs? just to validate the user without having to contact the server? in which case I should get the id_token instead